# Копия своими руками изделия PiBox от KubeSail

Tags: raspberry-pi, nas

Собираюсь создать NAS хранилище своими руками. В интернете нашёл изделие PiBox KubeSail (https://getpibox.com).

Статья на хабре в главе "Готовые изделия" https://habr.com/ru/companies/first/articles/592307/

Можете дать ссылки на карту расширения для Raspberry Pi CM4 и плату расширения для дисков.

Расскажите о нюансках если они есть о комплектующих,на которые я попросил ссылки.